# To calculate Number of days difference between two tables entries and update it in another table using SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCJSC.png)I have two tables A and B where, A contains todays data only and B contains historical data,
both tables have same attributes- pcode, product, market, pceneter, date. where All columns have same entry except date as for table A date is todays date and for B date is the first entry date in the table

I am trying to calculate day difference for A table's records available in B

```
Example: Table A 
          code   product   market   center       date      No.of Days
           X1     abcd      IT04     2G        17/9/2021      0
           X1     efgh      ER90     MB        17/9/2021      0
           Y5     ijkl      OK09     MB        17/9/2021      0

Table B 
          code   product   market   center       date
           X1     abcd      IT04     2G        15/9/2021  
           X1     efgh      ER90     MB        16/9/2021 
           X1     abcd      IT04     2G        11/9/2021  
           X1     efgh      ER90     C8        11/9/2021
```

expected output - Table A No of days should be updated with date difference for each reco available in talbe B

```
Example: Table A 
          code   product   market   center       date      No.of Days
           X1     abcd      IT04     2G        17/9/2021      6
           X1     efgh      ER90     MB        17/9/2021      1
           Y5     ijkl      OK09     MB        17/9/2021      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my solution:     

1. I grouped the  table B to get the minimum date with other columns.
2. Afterwards, i joined this subquery and table B to match and subtruct dates
```

Note: i may did some syntax problems, since i dont have any data / table to test it. But i hope you get the logic...

```
 select a.*, DATEDIFF(day, a.date, h.date) as no_of_days
      from table_a a
      left join (select code, product, market, center, min(date) date
                   from table_b
                   group by code, product, market, center) h
        on a.code = h.code
       and a.product = h.product
       and a.market = h.market
       and a.center = h.center
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, as you suggested I grouped the table and there only added one more column with no of days difference count and later updated that count in table A with the record matching condition. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Cool-Dip i am glad it helped <3